# Google search place api, places not found

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-places-api

Somes places are not found from google api,
It used to return results before the last update but it does not anymore.

examples :

Pizza hut - france

Domino's pizza - france

In & out burger - los angeles

etc..

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?sensor=false&location=34.029900,-118.255463&radius=5000&key=API_KEY&name=In-N-Out%20Burger

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?sensor=false&location=48.847194,2.408152&radius=5000&key=API_KEY&name=Pizza%20Hut

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?sensor=false&location=48.847194,2.408152&radius=5000&key=API_KEY&name=Domino's%20Pizza

Do you know why ?

Comment: Did you know that the places-API is experimental? By that, unexpected things may happen from time to time. Unexpected is e.g. that I get a result when I search for `in-N-out burgerx`

Comment: Yes i did but i had 100% success searches (only restaurants) before their update

Comment: When an experiment would always return the same reliable result  it wouldn't be an experiment anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same issue but solved it this way:

For spaces: have to enclose the whole name in double quotes: %22name%20with%20spaces%22
For quotes: have to encode them as a space: Domino%20s

I tried it with your pizza hut example and got results back with my key